# Linux start screen on startup

Tags: node.js, socket.io, gnu-screen, startupscript

I'm trying to start a screen session on startup, so I added my script at the end of rc.local

```
    screen -S ws sh -x /var/includes/websocket/start.sh;
```

But that doesn't work. My goal is to be able to run in a screen session (screen named ws) 2 commands:

Start.sh content:

```
   cd /var/includes/websocket

   node /var/includes/websocket/websocketServer.js 2>&1 >> /var/log/websocket.log' websocket
```

I also tried creating a  cronjob but still unable to start the script.

Any help welcomed!

Comment: The most reliable way I found to do that is starting the script using the distro GUI's startup list. Even `ifup/ifdown` failed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it! Seems that "node" is not recognized by rc.local so I simply had to use the full directory in the command:

Instead of

```
node /var/includes/websocket/websocketServer.js
```

Use

```
/usr/local/bin/node /var/includes/websocket/websocketServer.js
```